# Shopify GraphQL Pagination Without Using Cursor

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I have read the tutorial for pagination using the parameter `after:cursor` in this article https://shopify.dev/concepts/graphql/pagination. Unfortunately, I cannot use this because I want to generate a sitemap for all the products. As you know, we can only get 250 products maximum at a single graphql request. What I am building is something like this:

`sitemaps/products-1-250.xml`

`sitemaps/products-251-500.xml`

`sitemaps/products-501-750.xml`

and so on...

I want to make some query like this where I can get products from 251 to 500:

```
query GetAllProductsForSitemap {
  products(first: 250, page: 2) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        other-attributes
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But of course, `page` is not a valid parameter.

Is this achievable in Shopify-GraphQL?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the perfect sitemap for all your products that are generated for free for you by Shopify? Any reason you are re-inventing the wheel?

As for your request, the short answer is no. One uses cursors when using the GraphQL API for data. Alternatively, you are 100% free to use paging with the RestAPI, so if you have to, you can.

Comment: The XML sitemap that we are generating are custom. Most of the elements we want to add in the URL are in the tags. Some of the tags are even written as `size:XL` where XL will be added to the URL. And also, we need to generate three URLs for each product for three different languages.

Comment: I think the RestAPI is the route to go. Besides, XMLs are for robots and does not need to have a super fast rendering time.